# Gstreamer output rtp framerate is too fast

Tags: gstreamer

Here is my command:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc ! timeoverlay ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=50/1 ! queue ! nvh265enc !queue ! h265parse ! tee name=video_tee ! queue ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5600 auto-multicast=true sync=false qos-dscp=60 max-bitrate=12000000
```

Problem: No matter how i set the framerate, the output is about 250-300 frame/sec on the rtp.
For example: at 50/1 the execution time to rich 1 min in the video is about 10 seconds.
Other example: at 1/1 framerate to reach five minute in the stream is about 10 seconds too.
You can see it in the command line and also in an other output window (but it is bearly visible and lagging, but sometimes jumps forward)

Here is my command for playing the stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5600 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H265" ! rtph265depay ! decodebin  ! glimagesink
```

The rate which the video is played back is not deterministic, sometime it take more time to reach one minute sometime it take less. I have a similar issue with ffmpeg, so I suspect that I have some problems with my hardware encoding with video card.

Problem 2: I have to start my playback first, than start to stream. If I do it the other way nothing is displayed. I have zero clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try setting `is-live=true` in your sender pipeline, for example:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc is-live=true ! timeoverlay ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=50/1 ! queue ! nvh265enc !queue ! h265parse ! tee name=video_tee ! queue ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5600 auto-multicast=true sync=false qos-dscp=60 max-bitrate=12000000
```

Comment: Is-live=true worked for me. Any idea how to fix my second problem? It's not a problem with the playback because VLC behaves in the same way. Here's the SDP file:

v=0
c=IN IP4 224.1.1.1/127
s=LIVE VIEW
t=0 0
m=video 5600 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H265/90000

So if I open the file first and then the stream, it works. But if I start streaming first and then open it, it fails to start the playback.